# Comparing two rows with array formula to indentify differences and return "Last Change Date"

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, datestamp

I currently have an Excel Table which is edited by multiple users. I wrote some formula to compare the actual status with the last saved file. It works well, but as any array formula, it is extremely slow:

1. Macro copies all entries when I open the workbook (`Mirror FEP` Sheet)
2. Array Formula compares corresponding rows in the original Table and the Mirror Table to find any differences; if there was some modification, it returns `TODAY()`. If not, the previous date is written...

   `=IFERROR(IF(AND(EXACT([@[PTI-Nr]]:[@KIFA];INDIRECT("'Mirror FEP'!" & "B" & (2+MATCH([@[EAARCH-Nr]]; Table3[EAARCH-Nr]; 0))):INDIRECT("'Mirror FEP'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1; COUNTA($2:$2);4); 1; "")&(2+MATCH([@[EAARCH-Nr]]; Table3[EAARCH-Nr]; 0))))); INDIRECT("'Mirror FEP'!" & "A" & (2+MATCH([@[EAARCH-Nr]]; Table3[EAARCH-Nr]; 0))); TODAY()); TODAY())`

The formula is complex in order to find the right row in `Mirror FEP` even when the user changes the order of the original table.

I am familiar with the VBA solution, but my users need to `Ctrl` + `Z` all the time. Do you have any suggestion on how to speed up my Workbook? Alternative solutions are more than welcome!

Comment: You can paste both tables into separate arrays and compare the rows by a key column using dictionaries. That would take barely seconds.

Comment: Hi Damian, I am not sure about what you mean. A VBA Code to create an UDF? Or something else?